# Share Wishlist action showing blank page in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, frontend, magento2.3.4, wishlist, share-wishlist

When I click on "**share wish list**" button it is redirecting to "**<base_url>/wishlist/index/send/**" and showing blank page. I am using Magento 2.3.4 CE.
The system log shows the below error.
[image]

Is it Magento 2.3.4 version bug or another one? How can we solve this issue?

Comment: any error in log ?

Comment: I saw only the above mentioned screenshot error in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to developer mode to see specific bugs

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Also check the error log files in var/log. The specific log files you can check are system.log & debug.log

Comment: Hi @LitExtension Magento Migration, I am already in developer mode but the system not logging any message. I found the issue which is happening because of wish list image rendering.

Comment: If you share specifically the new errors you are having, maybe I can help you